# Blazor - on change event get entire object

Tags: object, events, blazor, onchange

``i have a series of questions that i need the end user to answer
i place the questions in a table and iterate through them to generate a row for each question

there are 4 controls for each row

1. use td to display the question
2. use td to use select drop down for user to select an answer
3. use td to use input to prompt for optional comment
4. use td for button to call method to validate the data and save if passes validation

my supervisor would like to save the user choice of the select without having to press the button, i can get this to work with on changed but i need to validate the comment, if the user selects 'Not Met', i need to make sure they entered a comment, i cant get this to work
, how can i access the comment field of the current question in the change event method
here is the table and the code behind. i dummied up some variables for compile but what i need is to access the comment field for this question`

sample:

[sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iIHy.png)

```
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="400px">Question</th>
                <th width="100px">Answer</th>
                <th width="300px">Comment</th>
                <th width="100px">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var myQuestion in myQuestions)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td>@myQuestion.QuestionText</td>
                    <td>
                        @if(myQuestion.Optional == false)
                        {
                        <select 
                            @bind="@myQuestion.AnswerText_Id"
                            @bind:event="onchanged"   
                            @onchange="ValidateAnswerText"
                            class="form-control mb-3" style="width:125px">
                                <option value="@myQuestion.AnswerText_Id">@myQuestion.AnswerText</option>

                            @foreach (var possibleAnswer in possibleAnswers.Where(q => q.QuestionId == myQuestion.QuestionId))
                            {
                                <option value=@possibleAnswer.AnswerText_Id>@possibleAnswer.AnswerText</option>
                            }
                         </select>
                        }
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input for="Comment"
                            class="form-control"
                               style="width:400px"
                        @bind="@myQuestion.Comment" />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                   
                        <button
                               class="btn btn-primary"
                               @onclick="() => ValidateAnswer(myQuestion)">
                            Save
                        </button>
                   </tr>
                }
               </tbody>
               </table>`

code 

using EnlivantSurveys.Data.Library;
using EnlivantSurveys.Data.Models;
using EnlivantSurveys.Data.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Global = EnlivantSurveys.Data.Globals.GlobalItems;

namespace EnlivantSurveys.Pages
{
    public partial class SurveySectionInput
    {
    [Parameter]
    public string HouseSurveyId { get; set; } = default!;
    // [Parameter] public int BatchId { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string SectionId { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public string SectionText { get; set; } = default!;

    SurveyService objServ = new SurveyService();

    List<SurveyQuestion> myQuestions = new();
    List<PossibleAnswer> possibleAnswers = new List<PossibleAnswer>();

    string answerdefault = "";
    string message = "";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    myQuestions = objServ.GetSurveySectionQuestions(HouseSurveyId, SectionId);
    possibleAnswers = objServ.GetPossibleAnswers(SectionId);

       }

    public void ValidateAnswerText(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
    string tmpAnswer = e.Value.ToStringNullSafe();
    string comment = "";
    string message = "";

    var myData = tmpAnswer.Split(":");

    bool isOk = true;

    PointInfo pointinfo = GetPoints(myData[0], myData[1]);

    string answervalue = pointinfo.AnswerValue;

    switch (answervalue)
    {

    case "0":

       if (comment == string.Empty)
        {`your text`
        message = "Comment Required !";
        isOk = false;
        }
        else
        {
        message = string.Empty;
        isOk = true;
        }
        break;

    case "1":

        message = string.Empty;
        isOk = true;
        break;

    default:

        message = "Answer Required !";
        isOk = false;
        break;
    }

     
    if (isOk)
    {
    objServ.SaveTextAnswer(
        Global.HouseSurveyId, myData[1], myData[0]);
    }

    }

    public void ValidateAnswer(SurveyQuestion myQuestion)
    {
    myQuestion.Message = "";

    string comment = myQuestion.Comment;
    string answertext = myQuestion.AnswerText;
    string questionid = myQuestion.QuestionId;
    string answervalue = "0";
    bool isOk = true;

    if (myQuestion.Optional == false)
    {
    PointInfo pointinfo = GetPoints(questionid, answertext);

    answervalue = pointinfo.AnswerValue;

    switch (answervalue)
    {

        case "0":

        if (comment == string.Empty)
        {
        myQuestion.Message = "Comment Required !";
        isOk = false;
        }
        else
        {
        myQuestion.AnswerValue = answervalue;
        isOk = true;
        }
        break;

        case "1":

        isOk = true;
        break;

        default:

        myQuestion.Message = "Answer Required !";
        isOk = false;
        break;
    }

    }

    if (isOk)
    {
    myQuestion.AnswerValue = answervalue;
    objServ.SaveAnswer(myQuestion);
    }

    }

    private PointInfo GetPoints(string questionid, string answertext)
    {
    PointInfo info = new();

    foreach (var possibleanswer in possibleAnswers)
    {
    if (possibleanswer.QuestionId == questionid)
    {
        if (possibleanswer.AnswerText == answertext)
        {
        info.AnswerValue = possibleanswer.AnswerValue;
        info.PossiblePoints = possibleanswer.PossiblePoints;
        }

    }
    }
    return info;
    }

    public void NavigateToSurveySections()
    {
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/SurveySections/{HouseSurveyId}");
    }
    }
}


i have searched the internet for days for a solution to my problem, and couldn't find anything that worked`
```

Comment: Consider the UX.  If the user selects `Not Met` in the select, they are unlikely to have entered a comment yet.  What do you save if the user decides not to enter a comment, but clicks elsewhere?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.